# redux-saga completes request on the second call

Tags: reactjs, async-await, es6-promise, redux-saga

I am writing a simple saga to reset user password via email. 
I am using a generated api client and my saga body looks like this

```
let CoreApi = require('../../../api-client/src/index')
let AuthApi = new CoreApi.AuthApi();

export function* passwordReset(action) {
try {
  let res = AuthApi.apiAuthForgotPasswordPost(action, requestCallback);
  let data = yield res;
  console.log(data)
} catch (err) {
  const error = err.response;
  yield put(passwordResetError(error.body));
}
}
```

I'm having a weird problem where `console.log(data)` is triggered only if I invoke the saga for the second time. The request is sent both the first time and the second time. Both responses are correct but it only logs on the second invocation. I have a Login saga which looks the same and works as expected. I'm sure I'm missing a small piece but can't seem to wrap my hand around it.

Comment: Please provide more details on how does your root saga look like, how do you invoke `passwordReset` saga and `AuthApi.apiAuthForgotPasswordPost` implementation.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it is a good practice to use `call` effect instead of invoking async functions (e.g. api calls) directly.